# Continuation of font type and font size across text environments

Tags: fonts, fontsize

In the following example, I using two different text environments to generate text visualizations: `texshade` and `adjustwidth`. The code calling `texshade` hereby generates formatted text in a different *font type* and *font size* than the code calling `adjustwidth`.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{texshade}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage[active, tightpage]{preview}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{15pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{preview}

    \begin{texshade}{test.fas}
        \setends{1}{1..10}
        \tintdefault{normal}
        \shadingmode{diverse}
        \allmatchresidues{Black}{White}{upper}{up}
        \hideconsensus
    \end{texshade}

    \begin{adjustwidth}{12pt}{0pt}
        Taxon\_1: Foo Bar Baz Qux\\
        Taxon\_2: Foo Bar Baz Qux
    \end{adjustwidth}

\end{preview}
\end{document}
```

How can I find out what *font type* and *font size* is set by default in `texshade`, and how can I continue to use the exact *font type* and *font size* in `adjustwidth`?

**Edit:**
The content of file `test.fas` are as follows:

```
>Taxon_1
TAAATGGATA
>Taxon_2
TAAATG---A
```

Comment: What's in `test.fas`?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. See edited post.

Comment: Does adding `\ttfamily` at the start of `adjustwidth` do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the default monospaced font is used in `texshade`, so all you need is to add `\ttfamily` at the start of `adjustwidth`. I also had to add `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` to get an exact match.